# Swift - Assign titles to multiple buttons

Tags: ios, uibutton, swift2

I have multiple buttons that all get their titles from an array. I would like to be able to assign the title with a loop, but I can't figure how to refer to each button as I go through the loop.

Currently I am adding each title with a line of code like this:

```
button0.setTitle(title[0], forState: .Normal)
button1.setTitle(title[1], forState: .Normal)
button2.setTitle(title[2], forState: .Normal)
button3.setTitle(title[3], forState: .Normal)
etc...
```

I have added an IBOutlet to each button, but I am also using tags for another purpose, so if there is a way to use tags to assign the titles, I would be happy to do that.

Any thoughts?

Comment: You can get a UIButton using tags this way :
`UIButton *button = (UIButton *)[self.view viewWithTag:7];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an IBOutletCollection

In your Swift ViewController, assign all your buttons to the below

```
@IBOutlet var buttons: [UIButton]!
```

Then to assign the titles

```
var buttonTitles = ["Button1","Button2"]

for (index,button) in buttons.enumerate()
{
  if buttonTitles.count > index
  {
    if let title : String = buttonTitles[index]
    {
      button.setTitle(title, forState: .Normal)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Just what I was looking for.